# Did all my tasks run when I debugged through Task.WhenAll()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I have some old code that contains the following:

```
  await Task.WhenAll(
                    ProcessSubscriptions(),
                    ProcessNotifications(),
                    ProcessRenewals(),
                    ProcessCheckDeletedOrders()
                );
```

I have just debugged it in VS 2022 on our DEV environment. All of those methods send emails, and I had a suspicion that the redirection to our test mailbox isn't working properly and they would send emails to real customer addresses even from DEV environment.

I put a breakpoint on the await.Task.WhenAll line, and on the first line of ProcessSubscriptions(). Then I ran the code. My first breakpoint hit, at which point I pressed F5 and my second breakpoint hit inside ProcessSubscriptions(). I stepped through the method in debugger, and realized it was indeed trying to send mails to live customer addresses. So I killed the process in VS.

Then I realized to my horror that Task.WhenAll() will start multiple tasks in parallel, and while I was debugging ProcessSubscriptions(), the other tasks may have run and sent emails to customers. The other methods are all of type `public async Task`, and I didn't put breakpoints in any of them.

Did the other methods run?

Comment: Probably.  But I imagine the most decisive way to answer this would be to test it.

Answer (score 2):

> Did the other methods run?

It depends on the method implementation and where the breakpoints were set up. If all breakpoints were before awaiting "first truly async" (like IO-bound operation to send the email) method invocation then that part runs synchronously and the following methods were not executed/tasks started.

For example:

```cs
async Task Do()
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); // "simulate" CPU-bound
    await Do1();
}

async Task Do1()
{
    Thread.Sleep(100); // "simulate" CPU-bound
    await Task.Delay(1000); // "simulate" IO-bound. Everything until here is executed synchronously
    // if breakpoint was here then other task would be started
}
```

Everything until `await Task.Delay(1000)` is executed synchronously. You can observe it by placing some console outputs in the methods and invoking several task in parallel:

```cs
var t1 = Do();
Console.WriteLine("between");
var t2 = Do();
await t1;
await t2;
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

[There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) by Stephen Cleary can help a little bit to understand what is happening.